# unexpected end of file while adding httpauth

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to secure my phpMyAdmin with nginx http auth but, when I add auth instructions, nginx -t says:

**nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:22

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name x.x.x.x;

    root /var/www/html/mypma;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location = / {
    return 444;
    }

    location = /pma {
    auth_basic "Area riservata”;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
    }
    
    location ~ .php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: `auth_basic "Area riservata”;` The second `”` is not a regular quote.

Answer (score 0):

The second " was not a regular quote. Thanks to @tkausl's comment!